# python 2.7 creating a array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary, collections

How could I do something like this in python

```
//Initailize array of objects.
 let myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon",position: null},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara", position: null}
],

//Find index of specific object using findIndex methode.    
objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));
myArray[objIndex].position= "manager"
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to do? There are thousands of questions about working with deserialized `json` data in Python. Can you give a sample input and expected output, at least?

Comment: So, to accomplish what you want seems pretty straight-forward with for-loop, no? Just loop over your *list* of *dict*s (we are in Python now) and `if my_dict['id'] == 1: d['position'] = 'manager'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple script to do what your question describes --

```
#! /usr/bin/python

obj1 = {"id": 0, "name": "John", "position": None}
obj2= {"id": 1, "name": "Sara", "position": None}

myArray = [obj1, obj2]

for i in myArray:
    if i["id"] == 1:
        i["position"] = "manager"

print(myArray)
```

Comment: This is what I needed!!! You are Awesome!!

Answer (score -1):

you can set list of object as :

```
list = []

list.append({
       EmpID:1234
       FirstName:Joe
})
```

Comment: Don't shadow the built-in `list` type constructor. Also, this code will fail with several `NameError`s.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What would you suggest. Is there a way where I could create two lists and then run a Join on EmpID somehow? I have to run the two apis in order because I create the second api from the first. How could I combine the data in python.

Comment: @WishIKnewthisstuff again, **you need to properly specify exactly what you want to accomplish**. The best way to make this clear is to give example input and output.